# Objectify queries: setting limit above 300 does not work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using Objectify with the App Engine remote API to query the datastore remotely. But I realized that setting the query limit to a value higher than 300 does not work. It fetches the entire data instead which eventually leads to to an out of memory error as the data is quite large. I need to set the limit to a higher value so the query can execute faster.

This actually used to work before but I don't why it's no longer working. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same behavior. It's unrelated to Objectify; this behavior happens when using the low level datastore api through the remote api. There's some sort of bug in the remote api. File an issue with Google?